# Make error centos5 missing separator

Tags: gcc, centos

```
#begin
# Copyright (c) 2009-2010 Satoshi Nakamoto
# Distributed under the MIT/X11 software license, see the accompanying
# file license.txt or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php.
CXX=g++
DEPSDIR=/Bitcoin/Deps
INCLUDEPATHS= -I"$(DEPSDIR)/include"
LIBPATHS= -L"$(DEPSDIR)/lib"
WXINCLUDEPATHS=$(shell wx-config --cxxflags)
WXLIBS=$(shell wx-config --libs)
USE_UPNP=
DEFS= -DNOPCH -DFOURWAYSSE2 -DUSE_SSL
LIBS= -dead_strip n
-Wl,-Bstatic n
$(DEPSDIR)/lib/libdb_cxx-5.1.a n
-mtl $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_system.a n
-mtl $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_thread.a n
-mtl $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_filesystem.a n
-mtl $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_program_options.a n
$(DEPSDIR)/lib/libdb_cxx.a n
$(DEPSDIR)/lib/libssl.a n
$(DEPSDIR)/lib/libcrypto.a n
-l ssl n
-l crypto n
-Wl,-Bdynamic n
-l gthread-2.0 n
-l z n
-l dl
ifdef USE_UPNP
LIBS += -l miniupnpc
DEFS += -DUSE_UPNP=$(USE_UPNP)
endif
DEBUGFLAGS=-g -D__WXDEBUG__
CXXFLAGS=-O2 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wformat $(DEBUGFLAGS) $(DEFS) $(INCLUDEPATHS)
HEADERS=headers.h strlcpy.h serialize.h uint256.h n
util.h key.h bignum.h base58.h script.h n
db.h net.h irc.h main.h rpc.h uibase.h n
ui.h noui.h init.h
OBJS= obj/util.o n
obj/script.o n
obj/db.o n
obj/net.o n
obj/irc.o n
obj/main.o n
obj/rpc.o n
obj/init.o n
cryptopp/obj/sha.o n
cryptopp/obj/cpu.o
all: bitcoind
obj/%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(WXINCLUDEPATHS) -DGUI -o $@ $<
cryptopp/obj/%.o: cryptopp/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -O3 -o $@ $<
bitcoin: $(OBJS) obj/ui.o obj/uibase.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBPATHS) $^ $(WXLIBS) $(LIBS)
obj/nogui/%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
bitcoind: $(OBJS:obj/%=obj/nogui/%)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
clean:
    -rm -f obj/*.o
    -rm -f obj/nogui/*.o
    -rm -f cryptopp/obj/*.o
    -rm -f headers.h.gch
    -rm -f bitcoin
    -rm -f bitcoind
#end
```

When I run this make file, I get an error of a missing separator on line 14 which is

```
-Wl,-Bstatic n
```

I can not figure this out for the life of me, so if anyone could be of any help to me that would be awesome!

If anyone is wondering I am building this of this guide http://www.staff.tugraz.at/michael.steurer/Bitcoin-CentOS5.5-V1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you're not using the Makefile which is in that document.

You're missing all the `\` at the end of the lines, you have no indentation (which is BTW relevant in Makefile).

Comment: Thanks! New to this realm of servers.